# How to read an element from a response

Tags: python

I want to receive the value inside the `<on>` element from a response.

```
response = requests.post(url)
```

the original content of this response will return a `byte` value instead of XML

```
data = response.text
# making sure that response is returned as string
print(data)
```

which gives me the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ok generator="zend" version="5.7"><on>1C96FY</on><co>K73Q5N0N15P3</co></ok>
```

Desired output

```
print(data)
------------------
1C96FY
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which framework are you using here

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.fromstring(your_text)
```